# Does operator of `[]` of std::map always put the new item into the first place of iterator?

Tags: c++, stdmap, yosys

Hi I've met a problem relating to iterator order of inserted values in std::map by operator [].

The code is a [github program](https://github.com/YosysHQ/yosys/blob/master/passes/proc/proc_dff.cc) in line 265: `many_async_rules[rstval].insert(sync_level);`

The definition of the map is `std::map<RTLIL::SigSpec, std::set<RTLIL::SyncRule*>> many_async_rules;`

By testing cases and guessing its meaning, this line should insert the `rstval` into the first iterator slot of `many_async_rules`.

However, in my machine it actually put the `rstval` into the last of it.

Thus I would like to ask if this is normal in `std::map`??

The following is some system info of my computer:

```
[shore@shore-82b6 yosys]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 11.2.0
Copyright © 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[shore@shore-82b6 yosys]$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=ManjaroLinux
DISTRIB_RELEASE=21.2.6
DISTRIB_CODENAME=Qonos
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Manjaro Linux"
```

Any extra info needed, please leave comment.

Comment: `map` is an ordered map. If the key is an integer, for instance, and the keys are 1 and 3, 2 will be added between 1 and 2, and 4 will be added after 3.

Comment: Your code has the definition `std::map<RTLIL::SigSpec, std::set<RTLIL::SyncRule*>> many_async_rules;` so `many_async_rules[rstval]` isn't an `std::map` it's an [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) (or reference to).

Comment: @G.M. Hi in latter it will iterate by `for (auto &it : many_async_rules)`, it suppose to start with the `rstval` inserted lastly

Comment: You aren't inserting into a map, you're inserting into a set.

Comment: @user253751 yes yes..... but the `rstval` is actually new to the map

Comment: @Shore okay so `insert` is irrelevant then. You are just asking about `many_async_rules[rstval];`

Comment: @user253751 yep, I'll change the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elements of `std::map` are stored in order of the key established by the `Compare` predicate that was provided to the map (by default, `std::less`). If `rstval` is the least key according to the predicate, then it will be the first element. If `rstval` is the greatest key according to the predicate, then it will be the last element.

> Which means that if the key is a pointer, then the order is not sure??

If the key is a pointer, and the predicate is `std::less`, and if the pointers are to elements of an array, then the order is the same as the order of the pointed elements in that array. But if the pointers are not to elements of an array, then their relative order is unspecified.

Comment: Which means that if the key is a pointer or an object, then the order is not sure??

Comment: Yes, for pointers their are ordered by their address in memory which is unspecified, except tge elements was allocated as an array.

Comment: what about an object in c++??? thanks a lot

Comment: @Shore What do you mean?

Comment: @Shore if it is an object it uses the `operator<` defined for that object

Comment: @Shore in C++ pointers and `int`s are objects too. Do you mean objects of some class type?

Comment: @caleth yep... like self defined class